# Connect car amplifier and capacitor

Tags: audio, wiring, capacitor

I try to connect my car battery, amplifier and capacitor.
I had to rearrange the position of the amplifier and the capacitor, and because of this I have not enough cable left.

**Before it was connected like this:**

```
Capacitor (+) --> Amplifier (+)
Amplifier (-) --> Car mass (-)
Capacitor (-) --> Car mass (-)
```

**Now It is connected like this:**

```
Capacitor (+) --> Amplifier (+)
Amplifier (-) --> Capacitor (-)
Capacitor (-) --> Car mass (-)
```

See picture (sorry for the wrong colors, I had nothing else in my repository)
[image]

Will it still fully work like this, or is it likely that I damage something? The car battery is disconnected at the moment.

Comment: Either should work fine, but what you show is probably better. Though I am not keen on you using a black wire for the +12V side....

Comment: Yes im sorry for the wrong colors, I had no red cable left :/ Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on how that looks, it *should* work.

That said, as mentioned, you should use the right colors, so I'd strongly recommend replacing you one black (+) lead.

Finally, while this should work, you do run a risk of distortion and *possibly* other noises... then again it could be totally fine. I imagine if you do get any distortion or anything like that it would be at peak.

Comment: I connected my batterie and it works fine, no distortions this far, I forgot to load the capacitor with a little lamp though, but I think the capacitor was not broken because of this.

Comment: Cool. The product is what matters and it seems like it's all good. In the future if you start having any issues (like I said, probably at peak ranges) I'd consider adding a proper grounding line for the amp as a first diagnostic action.

Comment: Is the color really that important? Is there any difference between the red cable beside the color?

Comment: @Black just to help people understand the circuit. If something went wrong and you needed someone else to diagnose your system they may come across that miscolored wire and become very confused.

Comment: I see. But in my case there is not many room for confusion, just a few cabels. I would never do this on a complicated system with many cabels.

Comment: @Black For sure. I've used wrong colors plenty of times for the sake of making it work. Nothing wrong with it.